# How do you embed a scripting language into a programming language?

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine

This question has been into my mind for years. Unity3D was developed by the help of  multiple programming languages, like C++ and C, yet we write code for Unity3D games in C# and JavaScript. How does that work?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.lua.org/start.html

Answer (score 0):

[image]please refer to unity documentation [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/IL2CPP-HowItWorks.html)
Unity Scripting API code is compiled to regular .NET DLLs (managed assemblies).

All managed assemblies that aren’t part of scripts
 (such as plugins and base class libraries) are processed by a Unity tool called Unused Bytecode Stripper, which finds all unused classes and methods and removes them from these DLLs (Dynamic Link Library). This step significantly reduces the size of a built game.

All managed assemblies are then converted to standard C++ code.

The generated C++ code and the runtime part of IL2CPP is compiled using a native platform compiler.

Finally, the code is linked into either an executable file or a DLL, depending on the platform you are targeting.